# Remove day name from highstock chart tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

How can i remove day name from the tooltip (highlighted in red) in high-stock chart.

[image]

Comment: You have to change the [tooltip](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip) options. Specifically the pointFormat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the standard `dateTimeFormat` for the day* label this chart uses.

* It might be you need to change something else as `day`, depending on your chart content. See the [dateTimeLabel](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats) API for all possibilities you can change.

```
 tooltip: {
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%b %e, %Y'
            }
        },
```

This changes the format to `Mar 01, 2000`, for example. 
If you want a different time format you can check out the [`PHP strftime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) which Highcharts uses for their formatting as stated in their [dateFormat API](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#dateFormat)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/e9d3s8cf/1/) you can find a working JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve this by editing your tooltip format during the declaration.

example of tooltip configuration

```
 tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return  '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' +
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b %Y',
                                      new Date(this.x))
            + ' date, ' + this.y;
        }
    },
```

You can also customize your X axis tooltip by using this doc :

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.tooltip

Comment: This code formats both the tool-tips which appears when i hover a series

Comment: @NKdev Try this to use plotOptions.series.tooltip.